# PMOS with floating source

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, fet

I'm trying to understand this example schematic from the [LTC4007](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4007.pdf) datasheet. It all makes sense for the most part.

[image: example schematic]

My question is around `Q1`, which is a PMOS. When there is no `DCIN` plugged in (the battery is not charging), the `SYSTEMLOAD` is driven using the battery voltage. The power path goes through the 0.025 Ω sense resistor, through the 10 uH inductor and through `Q1`. But how is `Q1` conducting? Presumably, `TGATE` is pulled low when there is no `DCIN` present, since the chip operates on `DCIN`. Therefore, for the MOSFET to conduct, the source of `Q1` must be pulled to a higher voltage (V<sub>gs</sub> < 0), but there are no pull-ups to the battery. What causes `Q1` to close/conduct?

I'm sure it some simple ignorance on my part on how MOSFETs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 and Q2 form a half bridge driver as part of a synchronous step-down ("buck") DC-DC converter.

Specifically:

While charging, when Q1 is on, Q2 is off, and vice versa. Q1 and Q2 alternate at a high frequency, to generate a rectangular wave (PWM - pulse width modulation) at a variable duty cycle. The following inductor and capacitor form a low pass filter to convert that PWM to a steady DC current into the Li-ion battery.

To answer your direct question:

- While charging: Q1 is on when Q2 is off, alternating at a high frequency. The IC turns on Q1 by connecting its gate to ground and turns it off by connecting its gate to the battery +.
- While discharging: Q1 is permanently on. Again, the IC turns on Q1 by connecting its gate to ground. The IC is powered through the CLN pin.
- While idle: both Q1 and Q2 are off. The IC turns off Q1 by connecting its gate to the battery +.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you saying that when discharging, the source terminal of Q1 is driven high by CLN? Where is CLN getting a high voltage from in the case that DCIN is not present? I understand that the gate is pulled low, I'm just not sure how the source of the PMOS gets a positive voltage

Comment: Not quite. Initially, CLN is powered by the voltage still on 30 20 uF capacitor, still charged from when the input power was present. Immediately, the IC turns on Q1. That keeps the capacitor charged. In the case the first thing that is connected in the battery (not the power input) then the capacitor is charged through the intrinsic diode in Q1 (not shown in that schematic diagram, but understood to be there in all commercially available MOSFETs). But that only occurs once.

Comment: Gotcha - that makes sense. Thank you so much!